# highcharts add series from array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add series from an javascript array, but it does not work.
My code shows:

```
var values=[];
for (var i=0;i<string.data.length;i++)      
    values[i]=string.data[i].value;
```

That sets values to [11,9,9,8,7,7,5,4,4,2]. Then for highcharts

```
$(function () {
$('#UniqueScanCount').highcharts({
...
    series: [{
            name: 'Unique Scans: ',
            data: values,
        }]
    });
});
```

The series does not show any data.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Does chart displays legend and titles? Do you have any errors in console? Also, make sure your data doesn't contains any NaN's and strings.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your `values` array, caused by the for loop or your `string.data`, here is a working example using a var for the `series.data` and your values arrary:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/UgVz6/1/)

```
var values= [11,9,9,8,7,7,5,4,4,2];    

$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: values
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array type and push the values:

```
var values = new Array();
for (var 1= 0; i < string.data.length; i++)
{
values.push([string.data[i].value]);
}
```

It is important that you use the push([]) in order to assign it to the data tipe in Highcharts.